# AD711 Noise Figures

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, noise, datasheet

I'm looking at the datasheet for the AD711. Why are there several different values for the input voltage noise given without any information to distinguish between them?

[image]

Datasheet: [AD711](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD711.pdf)

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  To get a helpful answer I'd suggest you need to highlight the values you are referring to, along with specifically where the confusion lies.  As it stands your question is almost certain to be closed.

Comment: If you take a look at the graph of input voltage noise density (TPC 17), the figures in the table maps pretty closely, so it look like those are the figures across frequency (decades of frequency apart).

Comment: @Peter Smith Ahh yes I think you're right, if you put it as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking closely at the datasheet, in particular the noise density graph, we can see that the figures appear to be at (close to) 10Hz and each decade above that to 10kHz.

As this is effectively the 1/f noise plot, we can assume that the noise density is flat above 10kHz up to some maximum, of course, limited by the device bandwidth.

[image: AD711 Noise Density Graph]